# PHP $_FILES[''] fica vazio antes da validação

Tags: php, file-upload

Boas,

Tenho um problema no meu cógido, eu tenho um upload de imagem e defini que o tamanho deve ser inferior a 2MB e 280 x 280 px.

O que acontece é que quando é feito um upload de imagem o $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'] deixa de existir, mas só quando a imagem é superior a 2 MB e não dá output a este erro.
E se for inferior aos 2MB mas com mais de 280 x 280 px, ele dá o output deste erro correcto.

E não estou a usar o input MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE acho que é assim que se chama.
Esta assim o input:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="perfil.php" method="POST" role="form">
<input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" onchange="av()" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Limite 2MB"></div>
```

Aqui vai o código de PHP,

```
define('MB', 1048576);
if(isset($_POST['avatar'])){
$img = true;
$nome = $_SESSION["tipo"].$_SESSION["id"];
$uploaddir = "C:/Program Files (x86)/VertrigoServ/www/teste/avatar/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['avatar']['name']);
$imageFileType = pathinfo($uploadfile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$upFinal = $uploaddir . $nome . "." . $imageFileType;
$uploadOk = 1;

  if(filesize($_FILES["avatar"]["size"]) > 2*MB) {
    $size = true;
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }

  if(!empty($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'])){
    $imgS = getimagesize($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);
    $imgW = $imgS[0];
    $imgH = $imgS[1];
    if($imgW > 280 || $imgH > 280){
      $pixels = true;
      $uploadOk = 0;
    }
  }

  if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ){
    $type = true;
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }

  if ($uploadOk == 1){
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"], $upFinal)) {
      $up = true;
      $avatar= "/empregos/docs/". $nome . "." . $imageFileType;
      mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE candidatos SET avatar= '$avatar' WHERE id = '$id'");
      header("Location:login.php?update=".$_SESSION['tipo']."");
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na variável global `$_FILES[]`, antes de fazer qualquer tipo de acesso aos parâmetros, deve verificar o valor do parâmetro `error`.

Exemplo

```
if( $_FILES["avatar"]['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK )
{
    /*
    Houve erro
    */
    echo 'código de erro do upload: ' . $_FILES["avatar"]['error'];
    exit; // interrompe outras execuções
}
```

Consulte os códigos de erro na documentação: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Realmente antes dos parâmetros o check no ['error'] resolveu automaticamente o problema. A variável $size é criada caso o file ultrapasse os 2 MB's.  Estou a usar ($_FILES["avatar"]["size"] > 2*MB) como foi mencionado acima, e que realmente foi útil já que desconhecia o pormenor do return de bits em vez de bytes. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: a medida é em bytes, não em bits..

Answer (score 2):

Atenção que a function filesize() retorna o tamanho em bits de um ficheiro, e recebe como parâmetro o caminho desse ficheiro (se não me engano). Portanto esta linha não está correta:

```
if(filesize($_FILES["avatar"]["size"]) > 2*MB) {
```

Deveria ser algo do género:

```
if ($_FILES["avatar"]["size"] > 2*MB) {
```

Alem disso, assim como o @Daniel Omine mencionou, é melhor também fazer a validação dos erros: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83154/14345

Answer (score 0):

> ATUALIZADO

`2*MB` = 2097152 **Equivale** a 2048 Mb

Logo você condiciona que `if(filesize($_FILES["avatar"]["size"])` deve ser maior que `2097152` para poder isso acontecer:

`$size = true;

$uploadOk = 0;`

Então, nessas condições, um upload realizado cuja imagem contém um valor **INFERIOR** a `2MB` o erro acontecerá!

> SOLUÇÃO

```
if(filesize($_FILES["avatar"]["size"]) < 2*MB) { 

  // caso você queira imagens inferiores a 2048 Mb

}
```

Comment: não é isso o meu ini.php está com upload_max_filesize = 8M e post_max_size = 8MB.    Obrigado

Comment: @andreisaac, ATUALIZADO!